# HTML5 canvas paint undo function for performance

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, todataurl

Hello i have a big canvas like a: 5000px x 5000px and many painting tools. I need to know whats is best solution to solve `undo` function without lags or very big usage memory. Now i try create each `mousedown` save my canvas to array with `toDataUrl` method.

As you think this is good method or i need searching better method solve this problem?

example with small canvas and with only one painting tool - pencil:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/azyPGN

**Html (partial):**

```
<canvas width="5000" height="5000" id="paint"></canvas>
```

**Save and Restore portion of code:**

```
var history = {
  redo_list: [],
  undo_list: [],
  saveState: function(canvas, list, keep_redo) {
    keep_redo = keep_redo || false;
    if(!keep_redo) {
      this.redo_list = [];
    }

    (list || this.undo_list).push(canvas.toDataURL());   
  },
  undo: function(canvas, ctx) {
    this.restoreState(canvas, ctx, this.undo_list, this.redo_list);
  },
  redo: function(canvas, ctx) {
    this.restoreState(canvas, ctx, this.redo_list, this.undo_list);
  },
  restoreState: function(canvas, ctx,  pop, push) {
    if(pop.length) {
      this.saveState(canvas, push, true);
      var restore_state = pop.pop();
      var img = new Element('img', {'src':restore_state});
      img.onload = function() {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 400);
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 600, 400, 0, 0, 600, 400);  
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: its nice no need to change.

Comment: i need test for bigger canvas but i think on the 5000px x 5000px in array save it's very big data..

Comment: Now u can see 5000px x 5000px canvas lagging than start drawing: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/azyPGN

Comment: Larger canvases take longer to render, so reduce the size of your canvas to close to the size of your intended display. Saving your history with .toDataURL is the least efficient way of saving because the entire canvas is converted to an image url. Instead, save the users drawing commands in an array and pop() the last command off the array to undo. If you do these 2 changes, your app will use magnitudes less memory and will not lag. Good luck with your project!

Comment: Saving to another canvas rather than to a dataURL will be much faster and way less memory consuming. But, as markE said, recording the basic draw commands and replaying all of them until the last save will be drastically faster and use very little memory. If of any help i made a few time ago a context2D recorder on a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/gamealchemist/b4bfj6uf/